# How to combine 3 steps in ant build.xml into one step for Netbeans to generate a signed jar to run in web start?

Tags: netbeans, ant, jar, sign

My web start app ran fine, but I realized there is a lib dir I need to copy into the tomcat ROOT dir in order for my web start app to work, but I want to just combine all my jars into one big jar so I just need to copy one file each time I update the project. I searched on the web and found a solution to combine all jars into one, with the following step, which was mentioned at : http://arunasujith.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-build-fat-jar-using-netbeans.html

I rewrote my build.xml to look like this :

```
<project name="Test_Tool" default="default" basedir=".">
    <description>Builds, tests, and runs the project Test_Tool.</description>
    <import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>
    <target name="package-into-one-jar" depends="jar">

        <property name="store.jar.name" value="Test_Tool"/>

        <!-- don't edit below this line -->
        <property name="store.dir" value="dist"/>
        <property name="store.jar" value="${store.dir}/${store.jar.name}.jar"/>

        <echo message="Packaging ${application.title} into a single JAR at ${store.jar}"/>

        <jar destfile="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar" filesetmanifest="skip">
            <zipgroupfileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>
            <zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar"/>

            <manifest><attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/></manifest>
        </jar>

        <zip destfile="${store.jar}"><zipfileset src="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar" excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA"/></zip>

        <delete file="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"/>
        <delete dir="${store.dir}/lib"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

But when I ran it, it said there are some files unsigned, and can't run from html page, so I did some more search and found a way to sign the jar file, which is mentioned at : http://www.asjava.com/ant/how-do-i-sign-jar-files-in-ant/

So I've come up with an script [ sign_jar.xml ] look like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="ant to create keystore and sign jars" default="signjars" basedir=".">
    <tstamp/>

    <property name="build.output.dir"               value="C:/Dir_Test_Tool/dist"/>
    <property name="build.classes.dir"              value="C:/Dir_Test_Tool/dist"/>
    <property name="verisign.key.store"             value="${build.output.dir}/.keystore"/>
    <property name="verisign.key.storepass"         value="asjava.com"/>
    <property name="verisign.key.alias"             value="asjava"/>
    <property name="verisign.key.pass"              value="asjava.com"/>

     <target name="signjars">
        <mkdir dir="${build.output.dir}"/>
        <genkey alias="${verisign.key.alias}" verbose="true" storepass="${verisign.key.storepass}"
                keypass="${verisign.key.pass}" validity="365" keystore="${verisign.key.store}">
               <dname>
                 <param name="CN" value="AsJava.com Group"/>
                 <param name="OU" value="Jim"/>
                 <param name="O"  value="AsJava.com"/>
                 <param name="C"  value="US"/>
               </dname>
        </genkey>
        <signjar jar="${build.classes.dir}/Test_Tool.jar"
                 signedjar="${build.output.dir}/Test_Tool.jar"
                 alias="${verisign.key.alias}"
                 storepass="${verisign.key.storepass}"
                 keystore="${verisign.key.store}"
                 keypass="${verisign.key.pass}"/>
     </target>

</project>
```

After all the changes, I needed to do the following to get the signed big jar file :

<1> Build my project in Netbeans

<2> In files view of the project right click build.xml file and then select Runtarget >> Other Targets >> package-into-one-jar

<3>  In files view of the project right click sign_jar.xml file and then select Runtarget >> signjars

Now it works as I wished : One big jar that is signed.
But that's 3 steps in order to achieve this, there must be an easier way, why can't it be done in one step ? So I combined the above files into one, which looked like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Test_Tool" default="default" basedir=".">
    <description>Builds, tests, and runs the project Test_Tool.</description>
    <import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>

    <target name="package-into-one-jar" depends="jar">

        <property name="store.jar.name" value="Test_Tool"/>

        <property name="store.dir" value="dist"/>
        <property name="store.jar" value="${store.dir}/${store.jar.name}.jar"/>

        <echo message="Packaging ${application.title} into a single JAR at ${store.jar}"/>

        <jar destfile="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar" filesetmanifest="skip">
            <zipgroupfileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>
            <zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar"/>

            <manifest><attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/></manifest>
        </jar>

        <zip destfile="${store.jar}"><zipfileset src="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar" excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA"/></zip>

        <delete file="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"/>
        <delete dir="${store.dir}/lib"/>
    </target>

    <property name="build.output.dir"               value="c:/asjava"/>
    <property name="build.classes.dir"              value="C:/Dir_Test_Tool/dist"/>
    <property name="verisign.key.store"             value="${build.output.dir}/.keystore"/>
    <property name="verisign.key.storepass"         value="asjava.com"/>
    <property name="verisign.key.alias"             value="asjava"/>
    <property name="verisign.key.pass"              value="asjava.com"/>

     <target name="signjars">
        <mkdir dir="${build.output.dir}"/>
        <genkey alias="${verisign.key.alias}" verbose="true" storepass="${verisign.key.storepass}"
                keypass="${verisign.key.pass}" validity="365" keystore="${verisign.key.store}">
               <dname>
                 <param name="CN" value="AsJava.com Group"/>
                 <param name="OU" value="Jim"/>
                 <param name="O"  value="AsJava.com"/>
                 <param name="C"  value="US"/>
               </dname>
        </genkey>
        <signjar jar="${build.classes.dir}/Test_Tool.jar"
                 signedjar="${build.output.dir}/Test_Tool.jar"
                 alias="${verisign.key.alias}"
                 storepass="${verisign.key.storepass}"
                 keystore="${verisign.key.store}"
                 keypass="${verisign.key.pass}"/>
     </target>
</project>
```

But the strange thing is : now it copies all the compiled directories under src into dist, if I delete them the result big jar won't run, I don't know ant good enough to correctly combine the above 3 steps into one, and don't know Netbeans enough to solve this problem, can someone help ?